# MongoDB account -- is it an administrator's account?

Tags: mongodb, users, mongodb-4.2

I'm more familiar with MySQL, but in my new workplace, I have to look after a MongoDB database (MongoDB 4.2.18 with Mongosh 1.1.9 running on Ubuntu 18.04.6 -- yes, it's old; upgrading is a problem for another day).  I don't know anything about MongoDB.  Unfortunately, the person who created it has left and left behind no documentation.  Now, I need to look after it.

What I have is a username and a password.  With that, I can login like so:

```
mongosh --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase "admin" -u "XXX" -p
```

I can list all of the databases by doing `show databases`.  But, I can't execute the command `show users`:

```
admin> show users
MongoServerError: not authorized on admin to execute command { usersInfo: 1, lsid: { id: UUID("b2c4e061-1b54-4b27-bdf2-bef330b38b4d") }, $db: "admin" }
```

I then tried to get a list of users.  And I think this is the command to do it:

```
admin> show collections
system.users
system.version
admin> db.system.users.find().pretty ()
MongoServerError: not authorized on admin to execute command { find: "system.users", filter: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("1801ce09-5c09-44eb-9b04-86eb35817eaa") }, $db: "admin" }
```

Together, this feels like my account isn't an administrator's account.  Would this be correct?

If so, is it possible to create a new account with full administator's privileges?  I have `sudo` access on the host machine.  If so, how would I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your configuration file (typically `/etc/mongod.conf`) to this

```
security:
   authorization: disabled
```

As precaution in order to prevent unauthorized connections, you may also set

```
net:
   port: 55555
   bindIp: localhost
```

Then restart the `mongod` service. Now, you can connect with

```
mongosh --port 55555
```

and you have all privileges on the database. Change the password and/or credentials of user `XXX` or create a new admin user. You can check existing credential [usersInfo](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/command/usersInfo/) command.

```
db.getSiblingDB('admin').runCommand(
   {
     createUser: "administrator",
     pwd: "secret"
     roles: [
       { role: "root", db: "admin" }
     ]
   }
)
```

Revert configuration changes and restart `mongod` again.

Comment: Ah!  That worked!  Thank you!  So, my guess was correct.  The previous developer who developed the system in-house and has since left, never left behind the administrator's password...  Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's administrator account... You just need to change to admin DB, where user information is. So, type "use admin" + enter. You can always check on what DB you are just type "db" + enter.

With your mongodump problem. Parameters --db= and/or  --authenticationDatabase= will solve your problem (depending your problem). Use mongodump --help

What to come to question how to see if your role is admin, use db.getUser("admin"). Check [here!](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  In the example above, I have typed `use admin`.  (I didn't show it, but the prompt has changed to `admin>`.)  I also used the same login credentials to run `mongodump` of the admin database, and it failed (other databases were ok).  Despite this, you reckon this is an administrator's account?

Comment: "Despite this, you reckon this is an administrator's account?" - I would have ask the same question. How can you know this?

Comment: Check my edit to the answer!